# styles object not rendering in classname using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with typescript project. I have created project with

```
create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
```

I have installed types after create installiation

My project is compiling succcesfully but classnames not rendering.

this is my code

```
    import * as React from "react";
    import InputGroup from "../../components/input-group";
    import Input from "../../components/input";
    import Form from "../../components/form";
    import Button from "../../components/button";
    import * as style from "./style.scss";
    import Icon from "../../components/icon";

    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import AuthWell from "../../components/auth-well";

    const form = [
      {
        name: "Email",
        placeholder: "Email",
        label: "Email",
        input: (
          <InputGroup>
            <Icon type="email" />
            <Input id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" />
          </InputGroup>
        )
      },
      {
        name: "Şifre",
        placeholder: "Şifre",
        label: "Şifre",
        input: (
          <InputGroup>
            <Icon type="password" />
            <Input id="Şifre" name="Şifre" placeholder="Şifre" />
          </InputGroup>
        )
      }
    ];

    export default class Login extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className={style.container}>
            <AuthWell>
              <div className={style.title}>Giriş</div>
              <Form settings={form} />
              <div className={style.forgot}>
                <Link to="login">Şifremi Unuttum</Link>
              </div>
              <Button primary block shadow>
                TAMAM
              </Button>
            </AuthWell>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

output

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRUrJ.png)

classname not rendering  and  its response blank page also I didnt understand what's wrong

this is scss file

[scss file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABLJ2.png)

Comment: Please show me your `.scss` file.

Comment: I added scss file screenshot @QuỳnhNguyễn

Comment: Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader and replace your className to `className="container"`

Comment: If you want to use className as variable. Please read https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames#usage-with-reactjs